# How to disable sidebar only in bbPress and not WordPress?

Tags: bbpress, forum

I am trying to integrate bbPress with WordPress, and the only thing in my way (for now) is the sidebar. How do I disable sidebar in bbPress?

I know that one way is to manually remove or comment out `<?php get_sidebar)(); ?>` in all bbPress template files.

But I would like to know if there a way that will allow me to quickly allow me to turn it on or off — like adding some code in functions.php etc.

Thanks.

Comment: For quickly turning it on or off do you want some sort of admin checkbox or some conditional logic in the functions.php? Because if it's just to hide it altogether or show it altogether then commenting the code is the fastest way.

Comment: @sanchothefat Yeah, that's what I have already done. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I manually commented out all instances of `<?php get_sidebar)(); ?>` in bbPress templates like so:

```
<?php //get_sidebar)(); ?>
```

Alternatively, you can simply remove the code as well. But I consider it a bad idea, in case you want to have sidebar in the future.